# Convert string with alternating key value pairs to a dictionary

Tags: python

I have that weird string (single line) where first field is a key, second is a value. It looks like this:

```
key1\val1\key2\val2\key3\val3\...\keyn\valn
```

What would be the best way to convert such notation to python dictionary?

Comment: You could use the split method, and then group the result into groups of two. After that, just use the dict constructor.

Comment: You have to have a '\' character in front of each '\' character. 

    key1\\val1\\key2\\val2\\key3\\val3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer.

```
a = "key1\\val1\\key2\\val2\\key3\\val3"
b = a.split('\\')
dc = {}
for i in range(0,len(b), 2):
    dc[b[i]]=b[i+1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a temporary list to split your string to:

```
s = 'key1\\val1\\key2\\val2\\key3\\val3'

temp = s.split('\\')
d = {k: v for k, v in zip(temp[0::2], temp[1::2])}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with:

```py
import re

string = 'key1\\val1\\key2\\val2\\key3\\val3'

dictionary = {match.group(1): match.group(2) for match in re.finditer(r'(\w+)\\(\w+)', string)}

print dictionary
```

**However**, note that this would work **only** if the key values are **only** characters (no space or underscores and stuff like that). In order to accomodate to such different cases, you would have to modify the *simple* regex I am using in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

This does it without any imports:

```
s = """key1\\val1\\key2\\val2\\key3\\val3\\...\\keyn\\valn"""
spl = s.split("\\")
m = {}
for i in range(0, len(spl)-1, 2): 
    m[spl[i]] = spl[i+1]
print(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

use split and itertools.islice

```
import itertools
def parse(ss):
    inp = ss.split('\\')
    keys, vals = itertools.tee(inp)
    keys = itertools.islice(keys,0,None,2)
    vals = itertools.islice(vals,1,None,2)
    nd = {}
    for key,val in zip(keys,vals):
        nd[key] = val
    return nd
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.7.12:

```
line = "key1\\val1\\key2\\val2\\key3\\val3"
line_data = line.split("\\")
line_dict = {}
print line_data
for i in range(0, len(line_data), 2):
    key = line_data[i]
    value = line_data[i+1]
    line_dict[key] = value

print line_dict
```